# Finding the mean using a function. vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function, mean

I'd firstly like to say I'm a beginner in vb.net and coding in general.

I'm trying to find the mean of the numbers in an array.

So far, my code is this.

```
 Function getMean() As Double
        Dim DblArray(lstbxInput.Items.Count - 1) As Double
        Dim totalsum As Double
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To dblArray.Length - 1
            totalsum += DblArray(i)
        Next i
        dblmean = totalsum / DblArray.Length
        Return dblmean

    End Function
```

In the end, I need for dblmean to return the mean value of the dblarray numbers. 
Would this be correct?
Well obviously it's wrong because I tried to print the value on a label and it always comes out as zero. Why?
Is there something wrong with the code? or was there something wrong in printing out the value?

Also, this is the code used to print out dblmean

lblLrgAns.Text = dblmean.ToString

it happens when i click a button.

Comment: it doesnt look like there is anything in your array.  set a breakpoint to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this

```
Dim DblArray(lstbxInput.Items.Count - 1) As Double
```

All of `DblArray` items are 0, but you never change any of the `DblArray` items in your code, so `dblmean` would also be 0. You need to assign each item of `DblArray` before calculating the mean.

I would guess this is related to your previous question: [putting a list into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229131/putting-a-list-into-an-array), so here's how your code should look like

```
Function getMean() As Double
    Dim DblArray(lstbxInput.Items.Count - 1) As Double

    'get the items from lstbxInput
    getNumbers(DblArray)

    Dim totalsum As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To dblArray.Length - 1
        totalsum += DblArray(i)
    Next i
    dblmean = totalsum / DblArray.Length
    Return dblmean

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to use the [`Enumerable.Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358946%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method which is sitting in the `System.Linq` namepsorts(so remember to add the `Import`).

```
Dim mean As Double = DblArray.Average()
```

In your case you need to initialize the array first. I guess the items in `lstbxInput` are already doubles.

```
Dim DblArrayAs As Double() = lstbxInput.Items.Cast(Of Double)().ToArray()
```